# Print spaces to every inputs in 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, tasm, emu8086

I found a similar search about this but it's not too much very clear to me. I am trying to add spaces in every letter letter that was printed in Assembly Language 8086.
What I did so far is put the space inside the loop but it's showing a different character and prints the exact same character and implement another push and pop for the nested loop but nothing worked.

I wonder if I did something wrong because most of the data are stored in DL registers.

```
.stack
.code
start:
    mov ah, 6 
        mov bh, 02h
        mov cx, 0
        mov dx, 184fh
        int 10h

    mov ah,2 
        mov bh,0
        mov dh,11
        mov dl,14
        int 10h

mov cx,10
mov ah,2
mov dl,' '
push bx
mov ah,2
mov dl,'J'
x: int 21h

dec dl

push cx
inc bx
pop cx

pop bx

loop x


pop cx 


mov ah,4ch
int 21h
end start
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to not understand what are `push` and `pop` good for.

```
push cx
inc bx
pop cx
```

Encapsulating a part of code with `push cx` and `pop cx` is necessary only if the code sequence (`inc bx` in your program) somehow changes the saved/restored register `cx` and if you need `cx` unchanged by the sequence.

Beware unbalanced `pop bx` in the loop between `x` and `loop x`. This will increase stack pointer by 2  in each iteration (10 times), which makes the program crash.

DOS function [Int 21/AH=02h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2554.htm) prints the character in `DL` and it will advance cursor position, so all the chores with scrolling window and setting cursor position is not necessary.

This code, assembled with TASM 4.0 as `tasm Connor.asm` and linked with TLINK 3.01
as `tlink /t Connor.obj` gives the executable file `Connor.com` which prints `JIHJFEDCBA`.
If your intention is to add a space behind each letter, just insert another invokation of `Int 21` into your loop (and don't forget to save/restore `DL` while the space is printed).

```
model tiny
.code
org 256
start:
  mov cx,10  ; Number of characters.
  mov ah,2   ; DOS function WRITE CHARACTER
  mov dl,'J' ; Start with this character.
x:int 21h ; Write DL and advance cursor.
  dec dl     ; Prepare the next character.
  loop x     ; Repeat 10 times
  ret        ; Terminate COM program.
end start
```